# Function in query builder not working with request or variable

Tags: laravel

I am try to learn how to use this to post properly. I am just starting on Laravel.... recently

Why this is NOT Working?

```
 public function getFunctionFromUserGroup(Request $request)
    {
        try
        {
            $abc = $request->get('usertypeid');
            return response() -> json(SystemFunction::whereNotIn('Function_ID', function($q){
                    $q->select('Function_ID')->from('TB_UserAccess')->Where('UserType_ID', $abc );})->get(), 200);

        }
        catch (\Exception $e)
        {
            return response(['error'=> $e->getMessage()], 422);
        }
    }
```

And Why this is working?

```
 public function getFunctionFromUserGroup(Request $request)
    {
        try
        {
            return response() -> json(SystemFunction::whereNotIn('Function_ID', function($q){
                    $q->select('Function_ID')->from('TB_UserAccess')->Where('UserType_ID', 1);})->get(), 200);

        }
        catch (\Exception $e)
        {
            return response(['error'=> $e->getMessage()], 422);
        }
    }
```

Comment: difference is `  $abc = $request->get('usertypeid');` in the second one you are not passing this variable to where clause

Answer (score 2):

You have to make `$abc` available inside the closure:

```
... function($q) use($abc) { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your code run properly you need to use $abc inside your function using use() try below code

```
 public function getFunctionFromUserGroup(Request $request)
    {
        try
        {
            $abc = $request->get('usertypeid');
            return response() -> 
                 json (SystemFunction::whereNotIn('Function_ID', 
                 function ($q){
                    $q->select('Function_ID')
                        ->from('TB_UserAccess')
                        ->Where('UserType_ID', $abc );})->get(), 200);
        }
        catch (\Exception $e)
        {
            return response(['error'=> $e->getMessage()], 422);
        }
    }
```